# C# - Unable to save a customized linq-to-xml file, with new elements in it?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm creating a new XDocument and inserting a root element "profiles" in it, then saving.

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("profiles.xml"))
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("profiles")
    );
    doc.Save("profiles.xml", SaveOptions.None);
}
```

And then later I wanna take users input and add profiles into the already created xml file:

```
XElement profile =
        new XElement(Player.Name,
            new XElement("level", Player.Level),
            new XElement("cash", Player.Cash)
        );

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("profiles.xml");
List<XElement> profiles = doc.Root.Elements().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < profiles.Count; i++)
{
    if (profiles[i].Name.ToString() == Player.name)
    {
        profiles[i] = profile;
        return;
    }
}
profile.Add(profile);
doc.Save("profiles.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

But for some reason, it will never add any new profiles?

EDIT: Also, if I manually create a new profile into the xml file, it won't customize either, so the problem is within Saving the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never actually doing anything to change any of the elements within the `XDocument` that `doc` refers to:

- If you find an element with the existing name, you're modifying the *list*, but that won't modify the document. You probably want to use [`XElement.ReplaceWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith.aspx):

  ```
  profiles[i].ReplaceWith(profile);
  ```

  Note that in this case you're not even trying to save the XML file again (due to the `return` statement), so it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve in this case.
- If you *don't* find the element, you're adding the `profile` element *to itself*, which certainly isn't going to modify the document. I suspect you want:

  ```
  doc.Root.Add(profile);
  ```

  In other words, add the new profile element as a new final child of the root element.

EDIT: Here's a different approach to try instead - I'm assuming any one name should only occur once:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("profiles.xml");
var existingElement = doc.Root
                         .Elements()
                         .Where(x => x.Name.ToString() == Player.name)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
if (existingElement != null)
{
    existingElement.ReplaceWith(profile);
}
else
{
    doc.Root.Add(profile);
}
doc.Save("profiles.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

Also, I would *strongly* advise you *not* to use the player name as the element *name*. Use it as an attribute value or text value instead, e.g.

```
XElement profile =
        new XElement("player",
            new XAttribute("name", Player.Name),
            new Attribute("level", Player.Level),
            new XAttribute("cash", Player.Cash)
        );
```

That way you won't have problems if the player name has spaces etc. You'd then need to change your query to:

```
var existingElement = doc.Root
                         .Elements()
                         .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name)" == Player.name)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Mahi: I've explained (twice) why replacing wasn't working - but see my edit which suggests a different approach, including restructuring your XML.